# Getting: ' Trying to get property of non-object' when trying to access the value in an array of objects

Tags: php, arrays, object, foreach, request

So from a Get request I get back a response in this structure:

```
{
  "chromeosdevices" : [
     {
         "somekey" : "somevalue",
         "annotatedUser" : "annotatedUserValue",
         "activeTimeRanges" : [
             {
                 "date" : "dateValue",
                 "activeTime" : "activeTimeValue"
             }
          ],
       "somekey" : "somevalue",
      },
   ]
}
```

How can I access both DateValue and ActiveTimeValue?

I have tried it with this code:

```
$dec = json_decode($response);
$filteredResults= array();
if (! empty($dec->chromeosdevices)) {
    foreach ($dec->chromeosdevices as $chromeosdevice) {
        $user['annotatedUser'] = $chromeosdevice->annotatedUser;
        $user['activeTimeRanges_date'] = $chromeosdevice->activeTimeRanges->date;
        $user['activeTimeRanges_activeTime'] = $chromeosdevice->activeTimeRanges -> activeTime;
        $filteredResults[] = $user;
    }
}
echo '<pre>';print_r($filteredResults);echo '</pre>';
```

However, I only get back the annotatedUser, but not the date and active time. Why is that?

Comment: `activeTimeRanges` is an array of objects. You can't access the property directly. Either loop over them or access the first element as @WKoppel points out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is another object in an array use `$chromeosdevice->activeTimeRanges[0]->date;`

Comment: However as that data is in an array it strongly suggests that more than one of these _might/could_ exist. So another loop may be a better way of dealing with this

Comment: that is indeed true, i get back a lot of devices

Comment: Yea, I agree. I answered according to the question needs

Comment: @user3660293 It's better you accept RiggsFolly's answer as it works in general and would help others who come to your question looking for a solution. You can upvote this answer for fast help.

Answer (score 2):

That is in an array so maybe another loop would be the safest way to deal with this

```
$dec = json_decode($response);
$filteredResults= array();
if (! empty($dec->chromeosdevices)) {
    foreach ($dec->chromeosdevices as $chromeosdevice) {
        $user = [];     // init and remove last loops info
        $user['annotatedUser'] = $chromeosdevice->annotatedUser;
        foreach ($chromeosdevice->activeTimeRanges as $tr) {
            $user['activeTimeRanges_date'][]       = $tr->date;
            $user['activeTimeRanges_activeTime'][] = $tr->activeTime;
        }
        $filteredResults[] = $user;
    }
}
echo '<pre>';print_r($filteredResults);echo '</pre>';
```